# Run all test in file with ReSharper 5.x and VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mspec, test-runner, resharper-5.x, test-framework

Is there a way I can tell the R# (5.x) test runner to run all the MSpec specs in the current file?

Something like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut of the Visual Studio test runner is what I'm after, be it a shortcut or a context menu command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't the menu item *ReSharper -> Unit Tests -> Run Unit Tests* do what you want to?
When your cursor is placed between two tests methods, it will run all tests in the current class. When your cursor is placed outside a test class, it will run all tests in the current file.

Comment: Not with MSpec specs I'm afraid :(

Comment: hmm, yeah I conveniently skipped that part, as I don't have any experience with MSpec. ^_^

Comment: It should work, though. I use that feature with MSpec all the time.

Comment: I must be pretty boneheaded, because I did take a look again and, do you know, it just works. Can't see how I've missed this one. Thanks!